# Factoring $x^2 - 81$ versus $81 - x^2$ - Question on behalf of my middle schooler

Tags: polynomials, factoring

This question is to clarify the confusion my middle schooler has.

During factoring we factor the negative sign of the leading coefficient so why is that not done when we factor a difference of squares like $81 - x^2$? if written in standard form it would be  $- x^2 + 81.$ So why is this incorrect :

$$-(x^2-81) = -(x+9)(x-9)$$

His teacher expects the answer as $(9+x) ( 9-x)$

Would appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Comment: One factors as $x^2 - 81 = (x+9)(x-9)$, the other factors as $81 - x^2 = (9+x)(9-x)$, but the second one has the same factors as the first "up to sign", because $(9 - x) = -(x - 9)$.

Comment: Sorry! I messed up his original question so I rephrased it.

Comment: What you write is correct, but as with most homework, here's the problem: it isn't just "is this correct in the absolute sense, but is this in the expected form that you were told to write it in?" If the teacher gave specific instructions about how to write solutions to these kind of problems, then your middle schooler should follow those instructions. Note that $x+9$ is the same as $9+x$, and that $-(x-9) = (9-x)$. The two solutions are *equivalent*. But if you are told to write a book report in good English, and you submit it in German, it'll be incorrect even if the report is good.

Comment: The instructions were to identify if the given problem is a difference of squares and if so to factor it. It becomes confusing for students when she asks to factor the negative sign from the leading coefficient but says not to in such problems like difference of squares.From what I understand, mathematically if you factor a difference of squares , the answer - ( x+9)(x-9) correct ?

Comment: @Pearl: No, it's inaccurate to say "if you factor a difference of squares the answer $-(x+9)(x-9)$ correct".  Here, they are being asked to recognize a pattern: the pattern is that whenever you have a difference of two squares, $a^2-b^2$, then it is factored as $(a+b)(a-b)$. So, here, it is expected that they will recognize the pattern with $81-x^2 = (9)^2-(x)^2$ and proceed accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between finding "factors", and writing down a "factorization".

Factors are only determined up to sign. Consider integers, for instance: what are the factors (divisors) of $6$? Well, they are $2$ and $3$... and also $-2$, and $-3$, and $1$, and $-1$, and $6$, and $-6$. Same with $-6$. So $2$ and $3$ are both prime factors of $6$, and also of $-6$.

This does not mean that $2\times 3=-6$, though. If we want to write a *factorization* of $-6$, using *positive* primes, we need to add a $-1$: $-6 = (-1)\times2\times 3$.

Same with $x^2-81$ and $81-x^2$. They both have $x+9$ and $x-9$ as factors. But while $(x+9)(x-9)$ is equal to $x^2-81$, to get $81-x^2$ you need to add a sign. So either
$$81 - x^2 = -(x+9)(x-9)$$
or distribute the $-1$ into either of the factors to get
$$81 -x^2 = (x+9)(9-x) = (-x-9)(x-9) = -(x+9)(x-9).$$

With integers, we've decided that we will use the *positive* version of the primes ($2$ instead of $-2$, etc), and if we need to add a sign, we will just add the $-1$ at the beginning. That's why we usually write $-6$ as $(-1)\times2\times 3$, and not as $(-2)\times 3$ or $2\times(-3)$ (and why don't usually factor $6$ as $(-2)\times(-3)$, even though it is correct). That's a *convention*: an agreement we've made to make sure we come up with the same answers.

With polynomials, we've made a similar decision: we prefer *monic* factors, which are factors in which the leading coefficient is $1$. Because with polynomials it's even worse: it's not just the $-1$: you could also write, for example,
$$x^2 -81 = (17x+153)\left(\frac{1}{17}x - \frac{9}{17}\right)$$
(because the extra factor of $17$ cancels out with the extra factor of $\frac{1}{17}$). So we will want to factor $81-x^2$ as
$$81-x^2 = -(x+9)(x-9)$$
so that the factors, except for a single constant term at the beginning, are all monic.

Comment: Thank you so much Arturo Magidin & Rivers McForge